# find_if not working with const_iterator

Tags: c++

I wrote this program:

```
// splits a sentence into words
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "spacefunc.h"

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::find_if;

int main() {
    typedef string::const_iterator iter;

    string input = "This is me";
    iter i = input.begin();

    while (i != input.end()) {
        iter j;

        i = find_if(i, input.end(), notspace);
        j = find_if(i, input.end(), is_space);

        cout << string(i, j) << endl;

        i = j;
    }   

    return  0;  
}
```

It fails with following errors:

```
word_splitter.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
word_splitter.cpp:21:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘find_if(iter&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, bool (&)(char))’
         i = find_if(i, input.end(), notspace);
                                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:62:0,
                 from word_splitter.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:3806:5: note: candidate: template<class _IIter, class _Predicate> _IIter std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate)
     find_if(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:3806:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
word_splitter.cpp:21:45: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_IIter’ (‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’)
         i = find_if(i, input.end(), notspace);
                                             ^
word_splitter.cpp:22:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘find_if(iter&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, bool (&)(char))’
         j = find_if(i, input.end(), is_space);
                                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:62:0,
                 from word_splitter.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:3806:5: note: candidate: template<class _IIter, class _Predicate> _IIter std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate)
     find_if(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:3806:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
word_splitter.cpp:22:45: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_IIter’ (‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’)
         j = find_if(i, input.end(), is_space);
```

---

If I change `i, j` to `iterator` type, it compiles.

What am I doing wrong, as I am pretty sure that `find_if` accepts `const_iterator` type arguments?

**EDIT**
If this is the issue of `i` being a `const_iterator` and input.end() being an `iterator`, why does the following code work? This is from `Accelerated C++`.

```
vector < string > split(const string & str) {
  typedef string::const_iterator iter;
  vector < string > ret;
  iter i = str.begin();
  while (i != str.end()) {
    // ignore leading blanks
    i = find_if(i, str.end(), not_space);
    // find end of next word
    iter j = find_if(i, str.end(), space);
    // copy the characters in [i, j)
    if (i != str.end())
      ret.push_back(string(i, j));
    i = j;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: You have to use `input.cend()` with `const_iterator`

Comment: Please "fix" the code so that is shows the problem. Posting code that works, with a comment that making changes to it causes problems, does not show the problem.

Comment: To answer the latest EDIT: `str` is a **const** string reference; `str.end()` is, therefore, const. That is, the iterator does not allow modification of `str`, because `str` is const.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)'s signature looks like this:

> ```
> template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
> InputIt find_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p);
> ```

It expects its first 2 arguments to be of the same type. With `find_if(i, input.end(), notspace)`, if `i` is a `string::const_iterator`, it's not the same type as [`input.end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/end) which would be a `string::iterator` since `input` is non-const. If `input` was a `const std::string`, `input.end()` would return a `string::const_iterator`

---

Post C++11, it's uncommon to see a `typedef string::const_iterator iter`. Use of `auto` is more common:

```
string input = "This is me";
auto i = input.begin();
```

Comment: I am reading Accelerated C++ as my first introductory book to C++.

Comment: @RajatSaxena I'm sorry, I don't understand why that's relevant.... Is there something in this answer that's confusing?

Comment: I mean, I am not aware of `auto`.

Comment: Your answer is perfect. I solved my problem by making `input` variable `const`.

Comment: @RajatSaxena Ahh, okay, that makes sense. I'll still leave it in here. Glad this answer helped.

Answer (score 8):

`find_if` accepts non-const iterators and const_iterators; however, the iterators that you pass to it have to be the same type. The problem here is that `input.end()` returns a non-const iterator, because `input` is not a const object. That's not the same type as the const iterator 'i'. To get a const end iterator for a non-const object (or for a const object, but that's a distraction), use `input.cend()`.

Answer (score 5):

Others have explained why you experienced a compilation error. In my view, future mistakes can be avoided if you express more directly your "ultimate" intention, and let automatic type deduction take care of the rest. For example: if you want your input to be immutable, use `const` to mark it as such, and let `auto` take care of the rest.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool is_space(char c) { return std::isspace(c); }
bool is_not_space(char c) { return not is_space(c); }

int main() {
  const std::string input{"This is me"};

  for (auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end();) {

    it = std::find_if(it, input.end(), is_not_space);
    auto it_end = std::find_if(it, input.end(), is_space);

    std::cout << std::string(it, it_end) << "\n";

    it = it_end;
  }
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ clang++ example.cpp -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra
$ ./a.out 
This
is
me
```

Comment: My knowledge is very limited about C++, hence I was unaware of the fact that I can deliberately mark a variable as `const` and there is something like `auto`.

Comment: auto is a relatively new feature of the language, even some experienced developers are relatively unfamiliar with it.